# Why did the vuejs mustache syntax doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I start to learn vuejs and I can't explain this bug. The vuejs mustache syntax doesn't work in this exemple :

**the html file**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vue Basics</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next" defer></script>
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>test mustache syntax</h1>
    </header>
    <section id="user-goal">
      <h2>titre</h2>
      <p>{{ test }}</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**the js file**

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      test: 'bonjour'
    };
  }
});
app.mount('#user-goal');
```

Can someone tell me why i get this result?

Comment: try removing `defer` for the script tag cdn

Comment: Thanks but it's not working.